# htaccess 301 redirect after change in one part of the url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how do I redirect urls from old url to new url? Here is the case:

```
http://www.lorem.com/ipsum/dolor/sit -> http://www.lorem.com/ipsum/dolor/amet
http://www.lorem.com/ipsum/dolor/sit/lipsum -> http://www.lorem.com/ipsum/dolor/amet/lipsum
http://www.lorem.com/ipsum/dolor/sit/vulvat -> http://www.lorem.com/ipsum/dolor/amet/vulvat
http://www.lorem.com/ipsum/dolor/sit/lol    -> http://www.lorem.com/ipsum/dolor/amet/lol
```

The customer has renamed `sit` to `amet`. Do I have to create one redirect per link, or can I redirect `sit` to `amet` and all the pages under `sit` in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need only one RewriteRule to handle this.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(ipsum/dolor)/sit(/.*|)$ $1/amet$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you! That hit the spot! :)

Comment: What if there are number of segments are not fixed after amet i.e. what if amet/abc/dev or amet/abc/dev/got/cat or amet/ n segments

Comment: @ravisoni: Please open a new question with your requirements so that I can understand it better and suggest some rules.